# Domain Name from 123-reg, VPS from Linode. How to point to Google Mail for Business?

Tags: email-server, g-suite, mx-record, linode

I have bought a domain from 123-reg.co.uk and have successfully pointed it to the IP Address of my Linode VPS so that going to the domain serves up the pages from the Apache server running on the VPS.
The instructions I followed to do this are :
[image]

Now, I am trying to get the domain's mail handled by Google Apps for Business.

I have tried updating the MX records at Linode following this tutorial :
http://library.linode.com/email/google-mail

And also followed the instructions to update the MX Records in 123-reg's control panel :
[image]

I am slightly confused now. Where should I be adding the MX records? In my domain registrar's control panel or in Linode's VPS? Both have options to update the MX records.

Comment: DNS doesn't propagate. If you're still waiting for Google Apps to finishing validation (as stated in a comment below) read the Google Apps documentation and ensure you complete the necessary steps.

Answer (score 2):

As your nameservers are now pointed to linode, you have to setup every new record at linode. By setting your nameservers to linode, their nameservers are now responsible for resolving any dns query.

Comment: how long does it take for MX records to propagate ? It's been more than 12 hours and my in Google Apps it still says `MX records setup validation in progress`

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix **[here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/Tl8Bs3bjl3k%5B1-25%5D)** !

> Now the important part:
>   1. changed my mx records from UPPERCASE TO lowercase
>   2. clicked on "I completed these steps"
>   3. clicked on "I will do this later..."
>   4. clicked again on "I completed these steps"

It was only a matter of putting the MX record hostnames in lowercase.

Comment: strange, usually, the dns system isn't case sensitive ...